# Grey Out Windows Context Menu Entrys

Tags: windows, contextmenu

Is there a way to "Grey Out" or disable Windows Context Menu entrys?
I created a few entrys by adding them in the Windows Registry. So far so good. But they should not always be clickable (but still visible).
Googling this problem didn't help me. An Example is the Right-Click Menu of the Recycle Bin. When it's full the "Empty" -Entry is clickable, when it's empty it's greyed out.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127443(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok ... I was hoping for a simple solution, like adding a Registry-Key that says what the Entry should look ore behave like .. I stumbleded over this one as well but I have no knowledge about c++

Comment: If you can express the conditions under which the context menu is enabled in AQS, then you can use this: [Getting Dynamic Behavior for Static Verbs by Using Advanced Query Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171(v=vs.85).aspx#dynamic_behavior)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [Shotcut Menu Handlers (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144169(v=vs.85).aspx) or [Shell Extension Providers (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468984(v=vs.85).aspx)

It's not just about INI files and Registry entries. You'll need to implement a COM object that adheres to some interfaces, e.g. [IContextMenu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127443(v=vs.85).aspx).

A useful utility is [NirSoft ShellExView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).